# Google spreadsheet script remove protection in certain cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Let's say certain cells will be protected if it matches certain condition

```
function A() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var protection;

  for(var i = 3;i<ss.getLastRow();i=i+1){
    if(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()==7){     // check if the condition is matched
        for(var j=5; j<=20; j=j+2){
            if(ss.getRange(i,j).isBlank()){
              protection = ss.getRange(i,j).protect();         // protect that certain cell
              protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
              if (protection.canDomainEdit())
                protection.setDomainEdit(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to delete the protection I made on that cell if the condition changed, let's say the upcoming code will be:

```
    if(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()<=6){
    ...
```

How can I only delete the protection applied to that cell instead of all the protection in the entire sheet?
Thank you

I tried

```
getProtections().remove()
```

but it does not target certain cells right?

Comment: I would probably want to start with a rangelist of areas that I wish to unprotect.

Comment: Are you planning to run both scripts using triggers?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to unprotect the cells when the value of column "D" is less than 6.
- About `Now I want to delete the protection I made on that cell if the condition changed`, when I saw your showing script for protecting the cells, it seems that when the if-statement of `if(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()==7){}` is true, the empty cells of the row are protected. From this situation, in your goal, when the if statement of `if(ss.getRange(i,4).getValue()<=6){}` is true, you want to remove all protected cells of the row.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script? In this case, the protected ranges can be retrieved with `getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)`.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, when this script is run, the protected cells are unprotected by searching the values of column "D".

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
  var protects = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).reduce((o, p) => {
    var row = p.getRange().getRow();
    o[row] = o[row] ? [...o[row], p] : [p];
    return o;
  }, {});
  var values = ss.getRange(3, 4, ss.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues();
  values.forEach(([d], i) => {
    if (d <= 6) {
      var obj = protects[i + 3];
      if (obj) {
        obj.forEach(p => p.remove());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample, when the cells of column "D" is edited, the script is run by the installable OnEdit trigger. So, [please install the OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you use this script, please edit the cells of column "D". By this, the script is run. **When this script is directly run by the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.**

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 4 || range.rowStart < 3 || range.getValue() > 6) return;
  var protects = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).reduce((o, p) => {
    var row = p.getRange().getRow();
    o[row] = o[row] ? [...o[row], p] : [p];
    return o;
  }, {});
  var obj = protects[range.rowStart];
  if (obj) {
    obj.forEach(p => p.remove());
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- When I saw your script `A()`, I thought that when the script is modified, the process cost might be able to be reduced a little. So, how about the following modification?

  ```
    function A() {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
      var values = ss.getRange(3, 1, ss.getLastRow() - 2, 20).getValues();
      values.forEach((r, i) => {
        if (r[3] == 7) {
          for (var j = 4; j < 20; j = j + 2) {
            if (r[j].toString() == "") {
              protection = ss.getRange(i + 3, j + 1).protect();
              protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
              if (protection.canDomainEdit())
                protection.setDomainEdit(false);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [getProtections(type)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)